# Regex pattern with non-ASCII characters

Tags: python, regex

## Problem summary

I have this regex python code:

*In*

```
lst =[' ', 'US$170.8980\xa0billion', '[2]', '\xa0(2018)']
for i in lst:
    pat = re.compile(r'([\x1F-\x7F]+).+(\d+)')
    results=pat.search(i)
    print(results)
```

I am getting this ouput with my regex pattern:

*Out*

```
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 11), match='US$170.8980'>
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 6), match='(2018'>
```

### Desired Ouput

Ideally, I want to get this output:

```
[US$170.8980-billion-(2018)]
```

Comment: The parentheses in your regular expression are for capturing groups, if you want to match a literal `(` you need to escape it `\('

Comment: What do you want,  a better pattern or a different way to do it ? It looks like both because you're inputting a list into a regex black box and coming out with a single string with hyphens..

Comment: A different way to do it. Until all desired information exists I don't care for hyphens or formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```py
string = 'US$170.8980\xa0billion'
pat = ''.join(re.findall('([a-zA-Z0-9$.])', string))
```

Adapted

```py
lst = [' ', 'US$170.8980\xa0billion', '[2]', '\xa0(2018)']
for i in lst:
    pat = ''.join(re.findall('([a-zA-Z0-9$.\s])', i))
    print(pat)
```

Alternative:

```py
(re.findall('([^�])', i)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but it still contains unwanted reference '[2]'

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this expression might be close to what you have in mind,

```
import re

lst =[' ', 'US$170.8980\xa0billion', '[2]', '\xa0(2018)']

output =''
for index,item in enumerate(lst):
    item = item.strip()
    if re.match('\[\d+\]',item) == None:
        if index == len(lst)-1:
            output +='-'
        output += re.sub(r'[^ -~]','-', item)

print(output)
```

not sure though.

#### Output

```
US$170.8980-billion-(2018)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually, I will use this code in scrapy xpath. I am not sure I can fit your suggested code there.